# remove first character from mysql field

Tags: mysql

I need advices in order to make a process on my list of values. I have a table `llx_societe` and some fields where one of them is `code_client`. This field looks like :

```
0099
00100
00101
00102
...
00998
00999
001000
```

I want to remove the first zero for all values between `00100` and `00999` in order to get `0100` until `0999`.

I wrote this command :

```
UPDATE `llx_societe` 
SET `code_client`= SUBSTR(code_client,1) 
WHERE `code_client` BETWEEN '00100' AND '00999';
```

But nothing, none lines are proceed.

Have you an explanation ?

Comment: Thanks for -1 ... I ask my question, with command line which could help more than one personn and I get -1 ...

Comment: SUBSTR was exactly what I needed. +1 :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SQL starts counting from 1 and not 0. Try this:

```
UPDATE `llx_societe` 
SET `code_client`= SUBSTR(code_client,2) 
WHERE `code_client` BETWEEN '00100' AND '00999';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  UPDATE llx_societe
    SET code_client= SUBSTR(code_client, 2) 
    WHERE code_client between '00100' AND '00999'
```

[MySQL SUBSTR() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET data = SUBSTR(FIELD, 2);
```

for example if there is table(userinfo) and field is username

```
UPDATE users SET username = SUBSTR(username, 2);
```